# Call a js function from jsf code

Tags: javascript, java

How can i call a javascript function from jsf file.
I have an **input text** in **xhtml** page
And a **js** function that changes the text value, regrading some conditions.
I want to change its value  by call the js function from a **java** method in a jsf file

Answer (score 0):

In JSF you never call Javascript from Java code. If you need to have Javascript to change text input value of the generated HTML then you need to have that JSF page define inline Javascript (or import Javascript file) that will be executed by some type of HTML DOM event such from `onload` or another HTML element.